# Set AllowEdit field-by-field on table control?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is there any possibility to prohibit edit on a single cell of a table?
Just to underline - I'm **not** talking about a grid but about a table control on a form.

Accessing a single cell via `<tablecontrol>.cell(col,row)` does not provide functions as `allowEdit` or `enable`.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the method gotFocus on the IntEdit control on the FRM:tutorial_From_Table with the following code:

```
public void gotFocus()
{
    ;
    intEdit.allowEdit(!(table.column() == 2 && table.row() == 2));

    super();
}
```

This code does not allow to edit the (2, 2) cell. I hope it will help.